# Cast function T-SQL to SQLSCRIPT HANA

Tags: t-sql, converters, hana, hana-sql-script

I would like to convert code from T-SQL to SQLScript, 
here is my sample select statement in T-SQL:

```
select cast ( 10 as binary )
```

Output is: `0x0000A`

When I write this code in HANA, I get this result: `3130`

How can I get this input `0x0000A` in Hana?

So when I type `select hextobin(0xA) from dummy` I get `10` but how can I get `0xA` from `10`?

Comment: Looks like it's converting the *string* `'10'` to binary, rather than the *integer* `10`. (In ASCII/UTF-8 character encodings, `'1'` is encoded as 31 and `'0'` is encoded as 30)

Comment: Yes, I wrote a new function to fix it :)